# Magento 2 I want to flush only homepage cache from admin

Tags: magento2, cache

I Want to flush only homepage cache from the admin side no other pages affected. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save  "Home" page one more time and it will reset cache for this page.

Or, if you want to do it programmatically, clear cache by tag

```
$this->_cache->clean(
    \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG, 
    [\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $page->getId()]
);
```